# How to convert large number to shorten K/M/B in Dart

Tags: dart

How can I create function that convert large number into shorten number with character in `Dart`?

like

```
1000 => 1K
10000 => 10K
1000000 => 1M
10000000 => 10M
1000000000 => 1B
```

Comment: the unit should be uppercase to avoid confused (m can be milli)

Comment: Sorry about that and thank you for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String toString(int value) {
  const units = <int, String>{
    1000000000: 'B',
    1000000: 'M',
    1000: 'K',
  };
  return units.entries
      .map((e) => '${value ~/ e.key}${e.value}')
      .firstWhere((e) => !e.startsWith('0'), orElse: () => '$value');
}
```

Comment: the unit should be uppercase to avoid confused (m can be milli)

Comment: how can convert 5821 to 5.8k  then please

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/number_display Try this plugin

Answer (score 9):

There is a built-in function in Dart that can be used and it's simple:

```
var f = NumberFormat.compact(locale: "en_IN");
print(f.format(12345));
```

to make it a method:

```
getShortForm(var number) {
  var f = NumberFormat.compact(locale: "en_US");
  return f.format(number);
}
```

for this to work import

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Refer to this doc for more https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html

If you are looking for a hard way:

```
getShortForm(int number) {
  var shortForm = "";
  if (number != null) {
    if (number < 1000) {
      shortForm = number.toString();
    } else if (number >= 1000 && number < 1000000) {
      shortForm = (number / 1000).toStringAsFixed(1) + "K";
    } else if (number >= 1000000 && number < 1000000000) {
      shortForm = (number / 1000000).toStringAsFixed(1) + "M";
    } else if (number >= 1000000000 && number < 1000000000000) {
      shortForm = (number / 1000000000).toStringAsFixed(1) + "B";
    }
  }
  return shortForm;
}
```

Comment: The first method works perfectly, thank you

Comment: This is a great answer I never knew about this.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach, if you only need the suffix. It may not be compiling, but this is the idea.

```
String getSuffix (int t)
{
    int i = -1;
    for ( ; (t /= 1000) > 0 ; i++ );
    return ['K','M','B'][i];
}
```

**Edit**

This is the mathematical way to do it, and it compiles. The point is you are searching for the amount of "groups of 3 decimal" places:

- x 000 - 1
- x 000 000 - 2

and so on. Which is **log**<sub>*1000*</sub> **number**.

```
String getSuffix (int num)
{
    int i = ( log(num) / log(1000) ).truncate();
    return (num / pow(1000,i)).truncate().toString() +  [' ','K','M','B'][i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Intl package does this as "compact" numbers, but it has a fixed format and it will also change with different locales, which might or might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Make a class and used its static method every where.**

```
class NumberFormatter{
  static String formatter(String currentBalance) {
    try{
      // suffix = {' ', 'k', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'P', 'E'};
      double value = double.parse(currentBalance);

      if(value < 1000){ // less than a thousand
        return value.toStringAsFixed(2);
      }else if(value >= 1000 && value < (1000*100*10)){ // less than a million
        double result = value/1000;
        return result.toStringAsFixed(2)+"k";
      }else if(value >= 1000000 && value < (1000000*10*100)){ // less than 100 million
        double result = value/1000000;
        return result.toStringAsFixed(2)+"M";
      }else if(value >= (1000000*10*100) && value < (1000000*10*100*100)){ // less than 100 billion
        double result = value/(1000000*10*100);
        return result.toStringAsFixed(2)+"B";
      }else if(value >= (1000000*10*100*100) && value < (1000000*10*100*100*100)){ // less than 100 trillion
        double result = value/(1000000*10*100*100);
        return result.toStringAsFixed(2)+"T";
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```